# Prove that there exists $a\in K$ and a unit vector $e \in H$ such that $(a,e)\leq (x,e)\leq (a,e)+\delta$ for all $x \in K$.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

**Problem**

> Let $K \subset H$ be a compact subset of a Hilbert space $H$ with diameter $\delta:=\sup_{x,y\in K}\|x-y\|>0$. Prove there exists an $a \in K$ and and a unit vector $e$ such that $$(a,e)\leq (x,e)\leq (a,e)+\delta$$ for all $x \in K$.

**Attempt**

This is equivalent to proving the existence of $a\in K$ and a unit vector $e$ such that $0\leq (x-a,e)\leq \delta$. for all $x\in K$. By Cauchy Schwarz, we only ned to show that $0\leq (x-a,e)$.

Alternatively, we need a linear functional with norm $1$ and an $a \in K$ such that $f(a)\leq f(x) \leq f(a)+\delta$.

Comment: I have added an answer ;As I am new and also learning functional analysis do notify me in case there is a problem

Answer (score 2):

Let $z(\neq 0)\in H$ .Define $e=\dfrac{z}{||z||}$.

Define $f:H\to \Bbb R$ by $f(x)=\langle x,e \rangle $ which is a bounded linear functional on $H$.

Now consider $f|_K: K\to \Bbb R$ i.e. restriction of $f$ to $K$. Since $f$ is bounded(continuous) and every continuous function on a compact set attains its minimum  so it has a minimum in $K$ .

Hence there exists $a\in K$ such that $|f(a)|\le | f(x)|$ for all $x\in K$

$\implies | \langle a,e \rangle |\le |\langle x,e \rangle |\implies \langle x-a,e \rangle \ge 0$

Comment: I have added an answer ;As I am new and also learning functional analysis do notify me in case there is a problem

Comment: I think I have two concerns: 1.) does the extreme value theorem hold in hilbert spaces? 2.) your last line should be $|(x-a,e)|\geq 0$ right? In other words..can't the inner product take on conolex values?

Comment: Every hilbert space is a metric space right? @user210552 and what is a "conolex" value?